# How to perform continuous Integration using Jenkins?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, continuous-integration

I've the basic idea about the Continuous Integration using Jenkins like- basic project setup, setting up  source code management bit-bucket and build the project. I have done this so far and following the same approach, whenever any commit done in bit-bucket, Jenkins trigger the build and i get the build status But in my organization there is no expertise who clearly tell us about how CI tool actually used in real time. So we are not aware of the scope and expansions of the Automation project in terms of CI tool.

Can some one guide us about this and guide us to manage the release using Jenkins ? also somewhere the terms `Jenkins pipeline` confused me what it is and why it used for?

I'm working on Agile, So after completion on each sprint we have to commit out code in master branch only. We are planning to create new branch for each sprint. The vague in my is, we can create the new branch, sprint wise and also create the Jenkins job as per branch, So after committing the new branch Jenkins will trigger the build for that branch. It is the right approach ?

Comment: continuous integration belongs under devops or software engineering, the test part in CI belongs here. can you rephrase the question to better reflect this SE ?

Comment: For [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) see here on Stack. In general I would say: there is no one _right_ approach. Only one that works for your needs (and your team). That is the _basis_ of being agile in my book. So what is the actual problem you want to solve?

Comment: @Ray Oei, Thanks, I want my automation project to be run in modularized way. Let's say I have 100 testcase which already in master branch and integrated with the Jenkins and also running successfully. But in next Sprint m creating 20 more testcase, this time I want these 20 testcase to be release and to be run  after those 100 tests. Is it possible to do this kind of configuration?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked on devops.stackexchange.com

Comment: @c32hedge, not an issue m closing it, will post there